# C# Nested generics treated differently when using constraints

Tags: c#, generics

When using nested generics, the compiler fails when used directly yet compiles correctly when using constraints.

Example:

```
public static void Test1<V, E>(this Dictionary<V, E> dict)
    where V : IVertex
    where E : IEdge<V>
{}

public static void Test2(this Dictionary<IVertex, IEdge<IVertex>> dict){}
```

The two extension methods above have ostensibly the same signature, but if I was to now try to run code such as:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<VertexInstance, EdgeInstance>();

dict.Test1();
dict.Test2();
```

the compiler would err on 'Test2' stating that it could not convert to the generic form with the inline nested generic. Personally I find the syntax for `Test2` to be more intuitive.

I posted this originally as an answer in a question which asked about differences between using generic constraints and using interfaces directly, but I am curious as to why this happens?

Comment: I think the Dictionary<VertexInstance, EdgeInstance> issue is a question of variance. I look forward to the answers.

Comment: These extension methods of course do not have the same signature.  `Dictionary<IVertex, IEdge<IVertex>>` is not the same as `Dictionary<VertexInstance, EdgeInstance>`.  @Payo is correct; this is a question of variance.  Classes cannot be co- or contravariant.  Interfaces can, but only if they're marked for it, and `IDictionary<K, V>` cannot be marked for it because it wouldn't be safe, so changing to IDictionary wouldn't help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding my comment:

These extension methods of course do not have the same signature. `Dictionary<IVertex, IEdge<IVertex>>` is not the same as `Dictionary<VertexInstance, EdgeInstance>`. @Payo is correct; this is a question of variance. Classes cannot be co- or contravariant. Interfaces can, but only if they're marked for it, and IDictionary cannot be marked for it because it wouldn't be safe, so changing to IDictionary wouldn't help here.

Consider if this were allowed.  Your Test2 implementation could look like this:

```
public static void Test2(this Dictionary<IVertex, IEdge<IVertex>> dict)
{
    dict.Add(new EvilVertex(), new EvilEdge());
}
```

EvilVertex and EvilEdge could implement the correct interfaces, but not inherit from VertexInstance and EdgeInstance.  The call would then fail at runtime.  The call to Test2 is therefore not provably safe, so the compiler does not allow it.

> Thank you for the answer; however, the constraints version could have the same code inside and would have the same issue, wouldn't it?

No!  The constraints version could *not* have the same code inside, because you can't convert from `EvilVertex` to `V`, nor from `EvilEdge` to `E`.  You *could* force a cast from the type to the type parameter, by casting first to `object`, but that would of course fail at run time.

> Also, why is variance controlled at that level?

Because one purpose of generics is to prove the code's type safety at compile time.

> Your dict.Add should have the compilation error not the extension method in my view.

As mentioned, the call to dict Add *is* a compiler error for the generic version.  It *can't* be a compiler error for the interface version, because in the context of Test2, all you know is that you're converting EvilVertex to IVertex, which is perfectly legal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; however, the constraints version could have the same code inside and would have the same issue, wouldn't it? Also, why is variance controlled at that level? Your dict.Add should have the compilation error not the extension method in my view.

Comment: Thank you for the further clarification. I wasn't thinking about the fact that the generics version is compiled to a specific type before use and the actual method isn't on an interface. Great answer!